# Making kwarg not be passed to function if it is None

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my python, I am writing a function that takes `**kwargs`. I am running into the issue where I am often passing `None` as a keyword value, and this feels like bad style. For example:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    if 'bar' in kwargs:
        return kwargs['bar'] 

def baz(x=None):
    print(foo(bar=x))
```

The problem here is that if `x`is None, then I would like it just to print nothing. How do you make the keyword argument not be added to `kwargs`if it is None?

Comment: you'll print the result of `foo` whatever it is. You want to return `""` when None?

Comment: Just use `if kwargs.get('bar') is not None:` then.

Comment: and return `""` if condition is not met

Comment: @ChristianDean: no, because `'bar'` is explicitly set to `None`. And `print('')` still prints a newline.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that @MartijnPieters. I misunderstood what the OP wanted. That's why I deleted my comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out, you will need to test for `None` if it is not an acceptable value. But, keep in mind that a function *always* returns. If no `return` statement is executed... `None` is returned.

So you actually need to check if the *output* is `None` if you want to avoid printing in that case.

```
def baz(x=None)
    out = foo(bar=x)
    if out is not None:
        print(out)
```

Alternatively you can make sure `foo` always explicitly returns, which might be better for reusability, but will make `baz` print `something_else` instead of not printing at all.

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    if 'bar' in kwargs:
        return kwargs['bar'] 
    else:
        return something_else
```

Answer (score 5):

If `None` is not an acceptable value, *test for that*. Either don't pass on `x` in `baz()` if it is `None`, or explicitly test for `None` in `foo`. You can combine testing for the key and for the value not being `None`, by using `dict.get()`:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    bar = kwargs.get('bar')
    if bar is not None:
        return bar
    # return something else
```

or just use a conditional expression to return a default, like an empty string:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    bar = kwargs.get('bar')
    return bar if bar is not None else ''
```

or return the default for any false-y value (`None`, empty list, `0`, etc.):

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    return kwargs.get('bar') or ''
```

Comment: How can I do it like this? It's overriding my default params https://gist.github.com/chrisdel101/882ed4c9aaa7fe5a1a881d5de1f3133c

Comment: @MoteZart: I can't make out what you are trying to do, sorry. `dict.get()` returns `None` as a default value. Perhaps you want to test if `paramA` is set *at all*? `if "paramA" in kwargs:`. Or remove `paramA` if it is present and `None`? You could use `paramA = kwargs.pop("paramA", None)`, then `if paramA is not None: kwargs["paramA"] = paramA`. That puts the key *back into `kwargs`*, if the value is not `None`. Or delete it from `kwargs` if it is `None`: `if "paramA" in kwargs and kwargs["paramA"] is None: del kwargs["paramA"]`. Either way you then just use `tester(**kwargs)`.